# Flutter Android Support Library Not Recognized

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am writing a Flutter wallpaper app and am calling Android Specific code and I need to ask the user for some permissions, I need to import `ContextCompat` for that but there is not option to import in the quick menu, so I read online and manually did it.

```
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
```

The problem is that Android Studio can't resolve the `support` symbol, I also read some forums online about that as well. The most common answer I found was to include add the android support library in the Gradle, which I have already tried but did not work.

***Any help would be dearly appreciated.***

Comment: What is your min api level?

Comment: @MusaUsman Were you able to solve your problem? I get exactly the same behavior with all the libraries updated. To make it most interesting - when I open Android project on its own, IDE doesnt report any problems and sees the support library. It's only in the flutter project that it fails to build and doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7` should automatically take care of the dependency of `ContextCompat`
e.g. adding following in the dependency -

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Here the version `26.1.0` would depend on your compile version.

Comment: I tried this but I am still facing the same issue, the IDE does not detect that I have added new Gradle dependencies, and maybe that's why it does not show import option for ContextCompat. I have tried restarting the IDE and my computer but  it didn't work.

Comment: It says "'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"

Comment: Assuming you used "Terminal" from android studio when your project is opened - "./gradlew build"